# The responsibilities of each component of the Model view presenter controller pattern (not to be confused with the MVC or MVP patterns)

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

This question is about the model view presenter controller pattern (not to be confused with the other well-documented patterns, MVC and MVP). This patter is a later version of the pattern family and it seeks to overcome some of their limitations and emerging side effects. My question is, what are the exact responsibilities of each of the presenter and controller components?

For example, does the controller call the database service retrieve a list of certain objects, the pass it to the presenter, who then filters this list and passes it to the view as combo box items?
or does the controller do all of that stuff then pass it to the presenter which in turn pass it to the view? What about coordination between different screens? Does the controller coordinate and traffic data between different related screens or is this passed from presenter to presenter?

I Looked up the pattern online but there is no clear explanation